# how to put an array of arguments in path url in twig

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to pass an array of string in pth url, how can i put the for in teh path

i try to make a button on a twig in a app symfony

```
<a href="{{ path('cheops_glpi_tracking_search', {'status[]':{% for statu in status %} statu {% endfor %},'cheops_Glpi':1,'fkEntities_cheops_Glpi':tracking.fkEntities.id}) }}" target="_blank" class="btn" style="border:none;border-radius:75%;
        border-bottom:3px solid #f03c0c;font:bold 13px Arial;color:#56504e;background:#fff;">
    Voir tickets
</a>
```

> Message : A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "operator" of value "%".

Une erreur s'est produite sur l'intranet ou vous n'avez pas accès à cette partie. Nous avons été automatiquement prévenu de cette erreur et allons régler le problème dans les plus brefs délais.

Comment: <a href="{{ path('cheops_glpi_tracking_search', {'status[]':{% for statu in status %} statu {% endfor %},'cheops_Glpi':1,'fkEntities_cheops_Glpi':tracking.fkEntities.id}) }}" target="_blank" class="btn" style="border:none;border-radius:75%;
        border-bottom:3px solid #f03c0c;font:bold 13px Arial;color:#56504e;background:#fff;">Voir tickets</a>

Comment: You cannot define an array as a single route parameter. What exactly is your use case why you want to do that? I.e. if you already have the status data upon rendering the template, doesn't it mean that you have the same information available in backend without passing it via route parameters?

Comment: i have the same route and i try to use it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can inline a for loop that way.
Instead you could join the elements the following way

`<a href="{{ path('cheops_glpi_tracking_search', {'status[]': status|join(' '),'cheops_Glpi':1,'fkEntities_cheops_Glpi':tracking.fkEntities.id}) }}" target="_blank" class="btn" style="border:none;border-radius:75%; border-bottom:3px solid #f03c0c;font:bold 13px Arial;color:#56504e;background:#fff;">Voir tickets</a>`

Comment: thanks i fix the problem by making a new variable {% set ma_var = status %} and <a href="{{ path('cheops_glpi_tracking_search', {'status': ma_var ,'cheops_Glpi':1,'fkEntities_cheops_Glpi':tracking.fkEntities.id}) }}" target="_blank" class="btn" style="border:none;border-radius:75%;
        border-bottom:3px solid #f03c0c;font:bold 13px Arial;color:#56504e;background:#fff;">Voir tickets</a>

Comment: status is already a variable so if `{'status': ma_var ,'cheops_Glpi'...` works `{'status': status ,'cheops_Glpi'...` will work the same.